# On click of anchor inside list item, list item will remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in JQUERY and javascript. In this piece of code, oclick of each anchor inside list item then list item will remove.
How can i solve this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
function f(a){
var aa = a.split("_")[1];
 $('#k_'+aa).remove();
}
        </script> 
</head>

<body>
    <ul> 
    <li id="k_1"><a id="1" onclick="f(this.id);">Click1</a></li> 
    <li id="k_2"><a id="2" onclick="f(this.id);">Click2</a></li> 
    <li id="k_3"><a id="3" onclick="f(this.id);">Click3</a></li> 
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance to all!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your links are not showing up in the first place as you did not set the `href` attribute.  This must be set on a link, if your links effects come from javascript, set it to `#`.

Secondly, your javascript is completely wrong, here is what your page should look like.

### Method #1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function f(a) {
            $('#k_'+a).remove();
        }
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <ul> 
    <li id="k_1"><a id="1" href="#" onclick="f(this.id);">Click1</a></li> 
    <li id="k_2"><a id="2" href="#" onclick="f(this.id);">Click2</a></li> 
    <li id="k_3"><a id="3" href="#" onclick="f(this.id);">Click3</a></li> 
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

However, since you are already using jQuery, the more appropriate solution is as follows:

### Method #2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="thelist"> 
    <li id="k_1"><a id="1" href="#">Click1</a></li> 
    <li id="k_2"><a id="2" href="#">Click2</a></li> 
    <li id="k_3"><a id="3" href="#">Click3</a></li> 
    </ul>

    <script>
        $("#thelist li").click(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

This separates your JavaScript and HTML, which is pretty much a standard good practice nowadays.  I would recommend using method #2 unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the obfuscated function name and variable names (or, if you abstract this in to a function, then name it something more readable).

You can remove the DOM element in one statement, however.

```
onclick="$(this).parent().remove(); return false;"
```